# I want to modify some variable state yet return a view

Tags: solidity

I wish to modify a mapping value `isUsed` in isValid if-else statement and return a boolean value based if else

I tried including the view keyword in the function declaration but it resulted in unaltered results

```
function createVoucher(string val )public
   { var stud= VKey[val];
     isKey[val]=true;
     stud.key=val;
     stud.count=1 }

function isValid(string  val)public  view returns(bool){
    if(isKey[val] && isUsed[val]==false)
    {var stud=VKey[val];
     isKey[val]=false;
     stud.count=stud.count--;
     isUsed[val]=true;
    return  true;}

    else return false  }}
```

`

I expected a created voucher would return true on first call of isValid() and false on subsequent calls

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Pincode{
    struct Voucher{
        string key;
        uint256 count;
    }
    mapping(string=>bool)isKey;
    Voucher[] public voucher;
    mapping(string=>Voucher) VKey;
    mapping(string=>bool) isUsed;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isValid` is declared as a `view` function, so when you call it, the code is just executed locally on one node and no transaction is added to the blockchain. This means it can't mutate any state.

You'll need to remove the `view` modifier if you want your function to change storage values. But note that transactions *do not have return values*, so you'll no longer be able to get the boolean value out. You may instead want to emit an event or use a separate function to check `isUsed`.

Comment: how then will I be able to trap unassigned vouchers cause the default for isUsed will always be false

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You may need to describe more of what you're trying to do.